# PHP Pass Value from variable with Js to another page

Tags: javascript, php, database, variables, mysqli

I'm trying to pass a variable to another page with JS.

I have a search function, which passes a Value to my search page with my Table. Now, I have to pass the search value to another page, when something gets updated.

I tried it with this code:

The variable (in search.php):

```
$searchq= $_POST['search'];
$searchq= preg_replace("/\[^0-9a-z}/i","",$searchq);
```

And JS for it to get passed:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".lieferclassone").change(function (e){
        var liefertone = $(this).val();
        var search ="<?php echo $searchq ?>"
        var info = {liefertone: liefertone};
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "searchcheck.php",
            data : info, search,
            success : function(response) {
                          $('#customers').html(response);
                        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

`liefertone` is my checkbox, which update the column which it is in.

searchcheck.php:

```
$searchq = (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) ? $_POST['search'] : null;
 echo $searchq;
```

But at the other page my echo get nothing, what i'm doing wrong?

regards!

Comment: Try using session, or cookies

Comment: Side note: no need for `isset` when you're using `!empty`, it will check if the variable is set.

Comment: `data : info, search,` id not how you send multiple variables as data. It should all be within one object.

Comment: thanks guys, it's working now ^^. looks like this is the solution RiggsFolly, thought i tried it already but seems like i wrote something wrong..
@El_Vanja Thanks, i will try it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will pass all the data from your JS, assuming that the

```
var search ="<?php echo $searchq ?>"
```

is actually done as part of the PHP script execution, because of course you cannot run PHP code in the browser where the javascript gets run

```
$(function() {
    $(".lieferclassone").change(function (e){
        var search = "<?php echo $searchq; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "searchcheck.php",
            data : {liefertone: $(this).val(), search: search},
            success : function(response) {
                          $('#customers').html(response);
                        }
        });
    });
});
```